# Force git log to display UTF8 in Windows Terminal

Tags: git, powershell, cmd, git-log, windows-terminal

I've started to use Windows Terminal as my git command-line tool, but It seems like Korean characters are not properly printed when I type `git log`, like:

[image]

I've also tried using `cmd` and `powershell`, but same thing also happened. (no screenshots)

But it prints properly in Git Bash, like:

[image]

What I've searched and tried:

- Typing `chcp 65001`
- Typing `set LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`
- Change administrative language setting (followed [this article](https://akr.am/blog/posts/using-utf-8-in-the-windows-terminal))

And all things above didn't solve my problem. Is there any suggestion to solve my problem? I want to use Windows terminal, not git bash :(

Comment: Those aren't Unicode characters, they are sequences of US-ASCII character, `<`, `E`, `C`, `>` etc. The very fact that one of the terminals you used showed the characters correctly proves this. It also proves that none of the changes you tried were needed

Comment: Those are generated by *your program*. What does that program do? Why is it generating those things? What program is it? R perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's just `git log`. I'll edit it to my question.

Comment: That's not "just". Windows uses Unicode natively, Linux doesn't. Strings in Windows are UTF16 (USCS-2 in the past). The system locale is used to convert single-byte text to Unicode for compatibility purposes and console output (before Windows Terminal). Linux on the other hand assumes everything is single-byte, depending on the LC_ encoding to decide how to treat the bytes in strings. `git log` uses the `LC_ALL` variable to decide what to output - encoded bytes or the actual text.

Comment: This means you need to either `set LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` *before* calling `git log` or set the environment variable permanently. `Git Bash` works before it sets the environment needed by `git log` before displaying the command prompt. It doesn't provide its own console

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you, I've solved my question.

Comment: BTW you'll find quite a lot of similar questions from data scientists on Linux/MacOS, as eg users in West Europe try to load either Eastern European or Chinese text and find their default encodings mangle the text. R and R Studio couldn't handle multiple encodings for some years and some R packages still require modifying the environment variables to read files in other encodings